# Правильная архитектура сервлета Java

Tags: java, servlet

Архитектура сервлета: слой **view**(.jsp) обращается к классу расширяющему **HttpServlet**. Данный класс анализирует запрос и вызывает команду.

Вопрос: можно правильный пример, в котором будет правильно организовано взаимодействие, т.е. будет реализован перечень команда(паттерн команда), сервлет будет вызывать нужную команду, передавая, если необходимо параметры.

PS: не судите строго за постановку вопроса, 2 день в сервелтах

Comment: вы в курсе, что jsp это тоже servlet?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, тогда я запутался. Есть dao, services, web. Куда входит класс расширяющий HttpServlet, jsp, html?

Comment: я не понимаю вашего вопроса. пробуйте начать с чего-то простого. а то у вас все в кучу.

Comment: Вопрос по структуре проекта: jsp входит в services модуль?html в web модуль?

Comment: посмотрите на [трехуровневую архитектуру](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0). есть уровни и есть технологии с помщью которых уровни можно реализовать.

Comment: правильные примеры есть тут https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/ (старая версия, потому что в новых, 6 и 7, технологии прошлого тысячелетия - jsp - уже не описываются ;-) )